# Use Console.Writeline with Ternary Operator in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the TryParse method to output the result but I am stuck at how to use the ternary output to display the result. Can someone please help..??

```
using System;
namespace Video1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string number = "100.51yutr";
            int Result_of_Conversion = 0;
            bool is_Conversion_Successful = int.TryParse(number, out Result_of_Conversion);

            is_Conversion_Successful == true ? Console.WriteLine(Result_of_Conversion) : Console.WriteLine("Check"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(is_Conversion_Successful  ? Result_of_Conversion : "Check");`

Comment: Sorry Rob.. it doesn't work. It gives an error saying "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'string'"

Comment: @TotalGadha you need to call `Result_of_Conversion.ToString()`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
is_Conversion_Successful == true ? Console.WriteLine(Result_of_Conversion) : Console.WriteLine("Check");
```

With

```
 Console.WriteLine(is_Conversion_Successful ? Result_of_Conversion.ToString() : "Check");
```

Comment: This works fine..!! Thanks. But could you please also explain why do you include the ternary operator condition inside the console.writeline method?? I mean what was wrong in the logic that I was following originally?? Thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome. This is because Console.WriteLine is not an expression, it does not return a value, or result in a value. Ternary need to produce a result, a value. Thus, you need to give it _values_ to choose from.

Comment: aahhh.. I see now. Brilliant.!! Thanks sir once again.. :)

Comment: One more thing. Why did you convert the Result_of_Conversion to string if using inside the console.writeline?? Why can't we just say  Console.WriteLine(is_Conversion_Successful ? Result_of_Conversion : "Check"); I mean writeline method does accept int inputs, so why convert an int type variable to string to pass to writeline method??

Comment: OK, this has nothing to do with Console.WriteLine, as you correctly noted - it accepts any type of value. `.ToString()` is required here to satisfy the ternary operator which has to return a value of a _particular_ type. You coerce the int to string in order to make both values strings, and as such the result value of the ternary operator is a string. If one value is an int while the other is a string, the ternary cannot determine the type of the end result.

Comment: I am sorry to go back to the drawing board, but I checked again, the solution you gave doesn;t quite work. If I change the string in my code to "100.51" instead of "100.51yutr", it still gives check as the output, while I want it to display the number (101 in this case)

Comment: What I want is that if the tryparse method works, then the output diaplayed should be the number whose string representation is stored in variable number. If it doesn't work, then it should give "check" as the output...

Comment: My solution is not related to how you parse strings. It only answers the question in the title - `how to use Console.WriteLine in a ternary operator`. But to parse `101.51` correctly, you cannot use int.Parse as the string doesn't represent an integer number. Try `decimal.Parse` instead. This will give you `101.51` as a decimal number. To get `101`, use `Math.Round`.

Comment: As in `Math.Round(Result_of_Conversion)` after parsing.

Answer (score 1):

More readable approach

```
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main() 
    { 
       string number = "100.51yutr"; 
       int Result_of_Conversion = 0;
       bool is_Conversion_Successful = int.TryParse(number, out Result_of_Conversion);

        var result = is_Conversion_Successful ? Result_of_Conversion.ToString() : "Check";
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mukesh.. :)